# NUXT: Incrementally populate VueX store on client-side from individual fully rendered pages

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am creating an product listing site that is completely composed of static files. I am currently using nuxtServerInit to call an API to get all the appropriate information for the site to generate all of the static files. However, when I populate the store with the entire API response (nearly 2MB), it will be included in all of the static generated files.

I though that it would be smarter to fetch() the product data on each of the product pages and populate the store if needed, but how would I be able to access this data from a component that might need that data BEFORE i actually visited the page. Is there a way to get the data from that page without having to store all of the data, all of the time?